# difference between git commit and git commit object and how each is stored

Tags: git, github

The amazing [git pro](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Branching-Branches-in-a-Nutshell) book, mentions the following:

> **commit object** that contains a pointer to the snapshot of the content
> you staged. This object also contains the author’s name and email
> address, the message that you typed, and pointers to the **commit or
> commits that directly came before this commit** (its parent or parents)...

and further,

> Your Git repository now contains five objects: three blobs (each
> representing the contents of one of the three files), one tree that
> lists the contents of the directory and specifies which file names are
> stored as which blobs, and **one commit with the pointer to that root
> tree and all the commit metadata**.

The first bold texts almost differentiate between *commit* and *commit object* without much clarifying it.  The second bold texts tell us that *a commit is stored* , but does that mean *a commit object is only temporarily created?* Git gurus, please clarify this to me.

Comment: The _real_ issue is the distinction between commit the command / verb and commit the thing / noun. As for the latter, we all know they exist, but we mostly get along without worrying too much about what they are from Git’s point of view.

Answer (score 3):

There's four kinds of objects in the repo's object db: blobs, trees, commits and (the annotated) tags. "A commit" is a commit object, stored in a repo's object db. That's it. You can actually build the zlib test/demo sources and `zpipe -d` a commit object's file to see exactly the text `git cat-file -p` will show you. It really is that simple.

Seriously: fetch the zlib source and build zpipe. Then do commands in a toy repo you build with `--template=` to shut off all the samples, or get *really* bare-bones and do this:

```
mkdir -p mytest/.git/{objects,refs}
echo ref: refs/heads/main >mytest/.git/HEAD
cd mytest
git status
```

to see that puts you in a fully-operational git repo. This is not a trick.  Now make a file and git add it and say `find`. Then make a commit and say `find` again. `cat` or `zpipe -d` the files that showed up in the repo.

Answer (score 1):

See [jthill's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65678559/1256452), but to some extent I'll note that this is "just" a terminology issue.  I put "just" in quote because terminology and semantics are crucial to actual *understanding*, and the phrase *mere semantics* kind of puts me on edge: semantics aren't *mere* at all.  They are essential!  Without semantics, nothing we say has any meaning.

A useful distinction is to say that a Git commit—the noun—refers to:

- the commit object, *plus*
- its supporting tree object and any sub-trees and blob objects

and therefore it's the entire saved snapshot *plus* the metadata.<sup>1</sup>  Meanwhile, a commit *object*—where we use the word *commit* as an adjective modifying the noun *object*—is merely the commit object itself, consisting entirely of commit metadata, since the saved snapshot is found indirectly through the `tree` line.

As [matt points out in a footnote](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65678391/difference-between-git-commit-and-git-commit-object-and-how-each-is-stored#comment116123033_65678391), we also have the verb form, *to commit*, which means to make one of these commit objects that uses a tree object that uses subtrees and/or blobs.

In the end, then, the semantics are:

- to commit: commit as a verb, meaning to make a commit;
- a commit: commit as a noun, meaning the whole ball of wax; and
- a commit object: commit as an adjective, modifying object, meaning the internal Git object that stores only the metadata part of the whole-ball-of-wax.

Humans being human, and natural language being what it is, you'll see the terms being used inappropriately, with the expectation that the reading/listening human will receive instead what the writing/speaking human *intended* to say.

---

<sup>1</sup>Note that this means that I disagree with jthill's definition, which defines *commit* and *commit object* as the same thing.  That's OK!  Different people can have different definitions.  The aim of the last claim before this footnote is that we should try to understand what someone else *meant*, even if that requires adapting to their terminology for a while.

Comment: I have to say you've got a good point about "a commit" usually implicitly also referring to the snapshot or even the entire history attached to a commit, or commit object, but I'd disagree about bundling it in as a necessary or integral part of it. Understanding that "a commit" is generally shorthand for "a commit plus its snapshot" or "a commit plus its entire history" in speech is fine. I think mushing them all into one is not.